# htpasswd problem: AuthType takes one argument, an HTTP authorization type (e.g., "Basic")

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu-18.04, .htpasswd

I've never come across this error before and a search on Google doesn't turn up much. I'm getting 500 Internal Server Error. Running Ubuntu 18.04.

Apache log:

```
AuthType takes one argument, an HTTP authorization 
type (e.g., "Basic")
```

.htaccess

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

/etc/apache2/.htpasswd

```
test:$apr1$iAZiDJQI$kx5QMVpowee3IG7eCf24X1
```

I've tried moving .htpasswd to the document root, changing permissions, setting owner to www-data, nothing works. AuthUserFile path is definitely correct.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I was having the same error with my .htaccess file, and this post turned up as the first result in Google.

The problem causing this error is your .htaccess file which is not using unix newlines.
The fix is easy, in e.g. Notepad++ open your .htaccess file, then from the menu:
Edit > EOL Conversion > Unix (LF)

Save the file and upload it and it will work, at least in my case it did.